# Accept class instance variable name as an argument

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class model with numerous instance variables (shortened to 2 here) and defined a .copyWith method so I could change one at a time.

```
class Entry {
  final String title;
  final String? notes;

  Entry({
    required this.title,
    this.notes,
  });

  Entry copyWith({
    String? title,
    String? notes,
  }) {
    return Entry(
      title: title ?? this.title,
      notes: notes ?? this.notes,
    );
  }
```

I've created a state manager and want to change the data as the user makes changes. To do so, I'm calling multiple methods (again, shortened to two here).

```
  Entry _unsubmittedNewEntry = Entry(
    title: 'Default Title',
    notes: 'Default Notes',
  );

  updateUnsubmittedEntryTitle(value) {
    _unsubmittedNewEntry = _unsubmittedNewEntry.copyWith(title: value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
  updateUnsubmittedEntryNotes(value) {
    _unsubmittedNewEntry = _unsubmittedNewEntry.copyWith(notes: value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

This works, but it's super verbose with each function needed to update each function. How can I accept two arguments in the 'update...' method with one being the variable and the other the value? Example...

```
  updateUnsubmittedEntryTitle(string, value) {
    _unsubmittedNewEntry = _unsubmittedNewEntry.copyWith(string: value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
  updateUnsubmittedEntryTitle(string, value) {
    _unsubmittedNewEntry.string = value
    notifyListeners();
      }
```

I get an error that 'string' isn't defined in the two versions of the code above.

Comment: why don't you use copyWith directly? `updateUnsubmittedEntry({String? title, String? notes}) => _unsubmitedEntry = _unsubmitedEntry.copyWith(title: title, notes: notes);`

Comment: @h8moss Ahh..didn't realize I could call the copyWith function, populate the args, and then not actually use them. Thank you!

Comment: Glad the problem was solved!